# Extract contents of the div?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

How do extract contents of the div in bs4:

```
>>> Doc
<div class="document">
<p>Text.</p>
<p>More text</p>
</div>

>>> type(Doc)
bs4.element.Tag
```

and I want to get

```
<p>Text.</p>
<p>More text</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.contents`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children):

```
>>> Doc = soup.find('div', {'class': 'document'}) # assuming soup is your main content
>>> for i in [x for x in Doc.contents if x != '\n']:
...     print i
... 
<p>Text.</p>
<p>More text</p>
```

Comment: I'm sorry -- perhaps I should have stated it -- but under div there might be arbitrary complex html: tables, lists, whatever.

Comment: @Adobe So just print the whole content of the div tag?

Comment: Yep: `<div ...>CONTENTS</div>` -> `CONTENTS`.

Comment: It works. Great. It is kind of strange to read in the whole thing just to get rid of the first and last divs.

Answer (score 0):

To get just the entire contents of the div, regardless of which elements are contained in it, use `soup.find("div").prettify()` to effectively get inner HTML.

Comment: I'm having troubles with utf8 using this. I don't even get if it stripped the divs as needed.